# How do I properly organize jars into one folder in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I used Maven to generate a Jersey project from command line, and I also used `mvn eclipse:eclipse` so that I can import my project to eclipse.

After I opened the project from Eclipse I see all the jars were in the root folder, how do I create a folder or package so that I can move all these jars into it?

[image: Eclipse Screenshot]

Comment: You can't but you can hide them.

Comment: @durron597 I created the project with maven from command line and then I did the mvn eclipse:eclipse, what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `mvn eclipse:eclipse`.

Just do `File` -> `Import` -> `Maven` -> `Existing Maven projects` and browse the folder where your `pom.xml` is and Eclipse will organize everything for you.

Comment: he needs m2e installed though

Comment: Eclipse for Java and for Java EE come with Maven Integration, have a look: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you aren't using Maven eclipse integration - [m2eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/). You shouldn't have to install it, it comes already with more recent versions of Eclipse, though follow the instructions in that link if you don't yet have it.

If you *just* generated the project, try deleting it and then generating it again *inside eclipse* with `New -> Other -> Maven Project`. If you have a lot of code written already, instead right click on the project and do `Configure -> Convert to Maven Project`. Once you've done that, you may have to do `Maven -> Update Project` project to straighten out your jars, and possibly remove them manually with `Build Path -> Configure Build Path`.

However, I recommend creating the project from within Eclipse, if possible.

Addendum: @cahen's answer is also correct; don't use `mvn eclipse:eclipse`.

Comment: Thanks, I simply converted the project into maven project and maven generated a folder that contains all the .jar files. Then I have to manually remove those .jar files from Java Build Path --> Libraries. I was trying out generating mvn projects from cmd, but I guess I missed someithing.

Comment: Thanks, I have decided to accept @cahen answer, as his answer pointed out exactly where I did wrong. But thumbs up for your answer.